# How do I set env variables in bash script for a packer image

Tags: bash, eof

I am trying to bake an AMI with Maven and Gradle in Packer. Below is my json file.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo yum -y update
sudo yum install -y httpd
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/apache-maven
cd /usr/local/apache-maven
sudo wget http://mirror.olnevhost.net/pub/apache/maven/binaries/apache-maven-3.2.2-bin.tar.gz
sudo tar xvf apache-maven-3.2.2-bin.tar.gz
echo "Maven is installed at usr local apache-maven #maven"
sudo mkdir /opt/gradle
cd /opt/gradle
sudo wget https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.4.1-bin.zip
sudo unzip -d /opt/gradle gradle-3.4.1-bin.zip
echo "Gradle is installed at opt gradle #gradle"
cat > set-vars1.sh
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.2.2
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export PATH=$M2:$PATH
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/gradle/gradle-3.4.1/bin
eval $(./set-vars1.sh)
```

I am unable to exit the script and unable to export the variables. How do I exit and run the script?

What I am trying to do is create an AMI instance with a packer for which I am writing the above script as a provisioner. I am able to download and unzip maven and gradle but the env variables are not getting exported.

So basically I want to set variables in an instance at runtime.

Comment: The last line of your script will not change the environment of the parent shells. This [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58814/how-do-i-add-environment-variables)  explains how you can modify variables of the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cat << EOF > set-vars1.sh
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.2.2
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export PATH=$M2:$PATH
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/gradle/gradle-3.4.1/bin
EOF
```

Comment: Got an error with the permissions ```/tmp/script_5973.sh: line 15: set-vars1.sh: Permission denied``` ; How do I add sudo permissions?I tried ```sudo su``` and ```su```

Comment: Solved the sudo part with ```sudo bash -c```

Comment: It is not clear what you are going to achieve with these commands, and also with `eval $(./set-vars1.sh)`. If you want to save change into the $PATH variable, you will have to do it in another way. See my [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58814/how-do-i-add-environment-variables) above.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are unable to quit the script because `cat > set-vars1.sh` is expecting data from the standard input stream. As long as you don't provide that input at the command line and follow it with an EOF (control-D), nothing will happen.
2. Subsequent `export` commands are not executed, since the script stays sticked at the `cat` command above.

Comment: does ```cat << EOF``` help me exit the file? I tried EOF but does not work.

Comment: Yes, see my second answer.